# React Redux missing in props validation and recommended pattern for initialising container from an external API using redux-observable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-observable

I am trying to learn how to use React with Redux in a Typescript environment. I am using the patterns suggested at [react-redux-typescript playground](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide/blob/master/playground/src/components/fc-counter.tsx). However, I am receiving the following error when trying to build the code listed below:

> 'courses' is missing in props validation
>
> 'courses.map' is missing in props validation

Has anyone else experienced this type of error? Is it a linting error from  eslint plugin:react/recommended?

I am also struggling to understand the process of initialising the default state from the redux store when retrieving data from an API using redux-observable. I have store, epics, reducers, actions etc. configured as suggested by patterns from the [react-redux-typescript playground](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide/blob/master/playground/src/components/fc-counter.tsx).  These are configured for fetching a list of courses from an API using a redux-observable. Subsequently, I have three actions and reducers defined:
1. FETCH_COURSES_ERROR
2. FETCH_COURSES_REQUEST
3. FETCH_COURSES_SUCCESS

How do I then trigger my CourseList container to start the process of fetching and rendering list of courses. Is it good practice to have the redux store fetch the initial state for list of courses ( FETCH_COURSES_REQUEST -> FETCH_COURSES_SUCCESS || FETCH_COURSES_REQUEST -> FETCH_COURSES_ERROR. In short I do not understand how to connect/trigger the epic to the CourseList container....

**Epic**
Middleware initialised and run in store module....

```js
import { RootAction, RootState, Services } from 'ReduxTypes';
import { Epic } from 'redux-observable';

import { isOfType } from 'typesafe-actions';

import { of } from 'rxjs';
import {
  catchError,
  filter,
  ignoreElements,
  map,
  switchMap,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

import { fetchCoursesFail, fetchCoursesSuccess } from './actions';

import constants from './constants';

export const fetchCoursesRequestAction: Epic<
  RootAction,
  RootAction,
  RootState,
  Services
> = (action$, state$, { courseServices }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isOfType(constants.FETCH_COURSES_REQUEST)),
    switchMap(action =>
      courseServices.default.getCourses().pipe(
        map(courses => fetchCoursesSuccess(courses)),
        catchError(error => of(fetchCoursesFail(error))),
      ),
    ),
    ignoreElements(), // ignore everything except complete and error, template does this
  );
```

**CourseList**

```js
import React from 'react';

import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { GridSpacing } from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import Course from '../../components/Course/Course';
import { Course as CourseModel } from '../../redux/features/course/model';

type Props = {
  courses: CourseModel[];
  // isLoading: boolean;
  // fetchCourses: any;
};

export const CourseList: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  const { courses } = props;

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: 20, padding: 30 }}>
      {
        <Grid container spacing={2 as GridSpacing} justify="center">
          {courses.map(element => (
            <Grid item key={element.courseID}>
              <Course course={element} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

**CourseList - index.ts**

```js
import { RootState } from 'ReduxTypes';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { CourseList } from './CourseList';
import { courseActions, courseSelectors } from '../../redux/features/course';

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  onFetchCoursesRequest: courseActions.fetchCoursesRequest,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  courses: courseSelectors.getReduxCourses(state.courses.fetchCoursesSuccess),
});

const CourseListConnected = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(CourseList);

export default CourseListConnected;
```

**App**

```js
import React, { Component, Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import ErrorBoundary from '../errors/ErrorBoundary';
import { NavBar } from './NavBar/NavBar';

// code splitting at the route level
// lazy loading by route component, we could take this
// a step further and perform at component level
// React.lazy requires that the module export format for a component uses default
const About = lazy(() =>
  import(
    /*
  webpackChunkName: "about-page",
  webpackPrefetch: true
  */ '../views/About/About'
  ),
);

const CourseList = lazy(() =>
  import(
    /*
  webpackChunkName: "course-list",
  webpackPrefetch: true
  */ '../containers/CourseList'
  ),
);

const Home = lazy(() =>
  import(
    /*
webpackChunkName: "home-page",
webpackPrefetch: true
*/ '../views/Home/Home'
  ),
);

type AppProps = {};

export class App extends Component<AppProps, {}> {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <NavBar />
          <Suspense fallback={<div>LoaderOptionsPlugin...</div>}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={Home} exact></Route>
              <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
              <Route
                path="/courses"
                render={(props): JSX.Element => (
                  <ErrorBoundary {...props}>
                    <CourseList />
                  </ErrorBoundary>
                )}
              ></Route>
              {/* <Route component={Error404}></Route> */}
            </Switch>
          </Suspense>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

**main.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import { App } from './app/components/App';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './app/redux/store';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement,
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. I used the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) react hook to trigger the request action for fetching the course list. When the CourseList functional component starts the initial state for courses is empty. It then, via *useEffect* hook, triggers a *fetchCoursesAsync.request* action, mapped to the *fetchCourses* dispatch property.

The *fetchCoursesRequestAction* epic then makes the ajax call and subsequently triggers an action of either *fetchCoursesSuccess* or *fetchCoursesFail*.

Next step for me is to understand how to respond to a failed fetch course request triggered by the epic and throw to a surrounding Error Boundary.....

```js
import { RootState } from 'ReduxTypes';

type StateProps = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  courses: courseModels.Course[];
};

const dispatchProps = {
  fetchCourses: fetchCoursesAsync.request,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps => ({
  isLoading: state.courses.isLoadingCourses,
  courses: courseSelectors.getReduxCourses(state.courses),
});

type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & typeof dispatchProps;

const CourseList = ({
  courses = [],
  fetchCourses,
  isLoading,
}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  // fetch course action on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCourses();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: 20, padding: 30 }}>
      {
        <Grid container spacing={2 as GridSpacing} justify="center">
          {courses.map(element => (
            <Grid item key={element.courseID}>
              <Course course={element} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Answering your first question: yes it is an eslint error coming from the `react/prop-types` rule, you can safely turn it off, there is no need for prop types with typescript.

Your second question, where should the second part of an async action be dispatched? That should be dispatched from in your redux observable epic, not redux itself, and not from a react container component.

The redux-observable docs have a simple example of handling async actions under `Real world example` https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html

Comment: Thanks @jay_aye_see_kay for responding. Appreciated, that answers first question :) Will adjust eslint rule to remove react-prop-types rule. Confused as to second question, have added information to my original question to include epic. Not sure how to hook this up to my container??? Cheers for link, will have a look....

Comment: i think we can do better as a developers community instead of proposing to turn off every single eslint rule